# c++ differs in levels of indirection from

Tags: c++

I got this error messages when trying to compile:

- error C2556: 'int *Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'BinaryBuffer Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)'
- error C2040: 'Encrypt': 'int *(const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)' differs in levels of indirection from 'BinaryBuffer (const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)'
- error C2556: 'char *Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'BinaryBuffer Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)'
- error C2040: 'Decrypt': 'char *(const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)' differs in levels of indirection from 'BinaryBuffer (const BinaryBuffer &,const EncryptionKey &)'

cpp file:

```
#include "Encryption.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#pragma intrinsic(_rotl8, _rotr8)

constexpr auto xorKeyLocation = 0;
constexpr auto numberOfBitsToRotateLocation = 1;

int* Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer& plainText, const EncryptionKey& key)
{
    const auto xorKey = key[xorKeyLocation];
    const auto numberOfBitsToRotate() = key[numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];
    const BinaryBuffer result;

    do
    {
        std::transform(
            plainText.begin(),
            plainText.end(),
            std::back_inserter(result),
            [&](const auto byte)
        {
            const auto xored = byte ^ xorKey;
            const auto shifted = _rotl8(xored, numberOfBitsToRotate);

            return shifted;
        });
    } while (0);

    return result;
}

char* Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer& cipherText, const EncryptionKey& key)
{
    const auto xorKey = key[xorKeyLocation];
    const auto numberOfBitsToRotate() = key[(std::vector<int>)numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];
    const BinaryBuffer result;

    std::transform(
        cipherText.cbegin(),
        cipherText.cend(),
        std::back_inserter(result),
        [&](const auto byte)
    {
        const auto shifted = _rotr8(byte, numberOfBitsToRotate);
        const auto xored = shifted ^ xorKey;
        return xored;
    });

    return result;
}
```

h file:

```
#pragma once

#include "Common.h"

BinaryBuffer Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer& plainText, const EncryptionKey& key);
BinaryBuffer Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer& cipherText, const EncryptionKey& key);
```

What im doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It's really odd that your "binary" buffer is of type `int*`. Normally these are `unsigned char*`. You may be allocating 4x or 8x as much memory as you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your functions doesn't match their declarations in the header.

Comment: What do you mean? I dont understand

Comment: The header declares a symbol named `Encrypt`, with a signature that accepts constant references to a `BinaryBuffer` and an `EncryptionKey`. The return type is not part of the signature (which just means you can't overload on the return type alone), but is part of the function's type. Later, the compiler sees your definition of the `Encrypt` function in the .cpp file. It knows it's the definition of the same symbol because the signature (scope, name, and parameters) is the same. But the return type is different (`int*` instead of `BinaryBuffer`), so it complains. Ditto for `Decrypt`.

Comment: Thanks :) but now I got another error: error C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const EncryptionKey' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Well, whatever `BinaryBuffer` is, it apparently doesn't implement `[]`, or at least a version that is `const`.